# Trouble installing Go correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go, installation

I successfully installed this on my Mac, just having trouble on Linux. I'm following along their doc https://golang.org/doc/install. I'm running a 64bit machine so I downloaded the 64bit archive. Once downloaded I run

```
sudo tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf ~/Downloads/go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

I created a `go` directory in my home folder. I have the structure

```
/home
--/chrism
----/go
------/src
------/pkg
------/bin
```

And I add the following to `/etc/profile`. After saving I run `source /etc/profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

In `src/` I added a directory `git.mycompany.com` and in their another directory called `test`. In `test/` I made `test.go` and pasted the block of code from the tutorial above in

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

When I run `go run test.go`, it outputs the following

```
chrism@ubuntu:~/go/src/git.mycompany.com/test$ go run test.go 
# fmt
Usage: pack op file.a [name....]
Where op is one of cprtx optionally followed by v for verbose output.
For compatibility with old Go build environments the op string grc is
accepted as a synonym for c.

For more information, run
    godoc cmd/pack
# runtime
Usage: pack op file.a [name....]
Where op is one of cprtx optionally followed by v for verbose output.
For compatibility with old Go build environments the op string grc is
accepted as a synonym for c.

For more information, run
    godoc cmd/pack
```

If I add more packages to my import statement, it'll output the documentation for all those packages as well.

EDIT 0:
I also tried to install with `apt-get`. I uninstalled and removed my previous changes and then installed. This resulted in the following when running:

```
chrism@ubuntu:~/go/src/git.mycompany.com/test$ go run test.go 
go build fmt: exec: "/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/pack": stat /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/pack: no such file or directory
go build runtime: exec: "/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/pack": stat /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/pack: no such file or directory
```

EDIT 1:
This is the output of running `go env`

```
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOCHAR="6"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: Why not just install it with apt-get? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

Comment: @OneOfOne I did, but I ran into a different issue. I'll give it another go and update my question with the issue

Comment: I'm not sure but if you get that error with the official package, you should submit a bug.

Comment: Show the output of `go env`.

Comment: Do not use apt-get. Versions are way too outdated. Take a look to https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

Comment: It sounds like you have artifacts left over from an older install. The newer versions aren't compatible, hence the errors. Hose out `/usr/local/go/...` before reinstalling. https://github.com/travis-ci/gimme is a simple way to install the latest Go version on Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree with @elithrar before installing anything else, first make sure you have totally removed go. You can check if its there just typing: which go. To install the latest version see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I ended up clearing go out completely, then using the script posted by @elithrar to install and it works now!

Answer (score 13):

These are the steps I followed for installing Go in my Ubuntu system :

**Short Version :**
1. Run following commands for installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y gccgo-go && wget http://golang.org/dl/go1.8.linux-amd64.tar.gz && sudo apt-get -y install gcc && sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.8.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz && echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

> **Note:** Changes the version number to install a specific version of Go. For example, to install 1.9 instead of 1.8 change the file name to go1.9.linux-amd64.tar.gz. The latest Go distributions can always be found at [the official Go downloads page](https://golang.org/dl/)

2. Setup workplace. (Point 6)

**Long Version:**

1. Download the binary release from [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgolang.org%2Fdl%2F). Use go x.x.x.linux-amd64.tar.gz for ubuntu.
   For version 1.4.2 you can type following in terminal.

   ```
   wget http://golang.org/dl/go1.8.linux-amd64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Install gcc for cgo

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gcc
   ```
3. Extract the tarball in /usr/local. It should create a go directory.

   ```
   tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.8.linux-amd64.tar.gz
   ```

   (Typically these commands must be run as root or through sudo.)
4. Add /usr/local/go/bin to the PATH environment variable.

   ```
   gksu gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Add following line in the end of file

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
   ```
6. Setup Workspace

   a. Create a workspace directory name go in your preferred location (**unless you are using the default go installation location**). I am using /home/vembu/work/projects/go

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/vembu/work/projects/go
   ```

   b. Export GOPATH

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```

   c. Add following line in the second last line

   ```
   export GOPATH=/home/vembu/work/projects/go
   ```

   d. For convenience, add the workspace's bin subdirectory to your PATH:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
   ```

   e. Finally .bashrc’s last two line should look like this

   ```
   export GOPATH=/home/vembu/work/projects/go
   export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
   ```

   f. Restart terminal.

Answer (score 10):

This method is how I usually install on ubuntu machines and never fails. Hope it helps you.

1. download go

   `wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz`
2. extract into /usr/local

   `sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz`
3. add these lines to modify ~/.bashrc

   `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

   `export GOPATH=$HOME/go`

   `export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin`

   `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`
4. save and reload sources

   `source ~/.bashrc`
5. verify installation

   `go env`
6. Create go directory

   `mkdir ~/go`
7. Try getting some package

   `go get github.com/smartystreets/goconvey`

**EDIT**

I have created a bash script which does the above automatically for you. It always points to the latest go version, so be careful with that.

`wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mauleyzaola/scripts/master/go/go.install.sh | sh`

Then, just reload `.bashrc`

`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I messed up with go env variables and could not able to change them. finally, your bash script helped me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen a system wide installation, so you could remove this line: `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` from `/etc/profile` source again this later file. All other steps you mentioned are not necessary at all.  And instead of restarting Terminal as mentioned by a previous answer, you will need to reboot your machine. So by the end all  what you have to do is to carefully follow the steps mentioned in the official documentation itself.